# graceful_stop.sh not found in HDP2.1 Hbase

Tags: apache, hadoop, hbase, hortonworks-data-platform

I was reading Hortonworks documenrtation to remove regionserver from any host of cluster (http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.1-latest/bk_system-admin-guide/content/admin_decommission-slave-nodes-3.html).
It uses **graceful_stop.sh script** . The same script is described at Apache Hbase book (https://hbase.apache.org/book/node.management.html)

I was trying to find this script but not able to locate it .

```
hbase@node ~]$ ls /usr/lib/hbase/bin/
draining_servers.rb   hbase.cmd         hbase-daemon.sh  region_status.rb  test
get-active-master.rb  hbase-common.sh   hbase-jruby      replication
hbase                 hbase-config.cmd  hirb.rb          start-hbase.cmd
hbase-cleanup.sh      hbase-config.sh   region_mover.rb  stop-hbase.cmd
[hbase@node ~]$
```

Is this script is removed from hbase ?

Is there any other way to stop a region server from anyother host of cluster. For eg - I want to stop region server 1 . Can I do this by logging into region server2?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the script is removed from hbase if you use package install. But you can still find it in src files.

If you want to stop a region server A from another host B, then host B must have privilege to access A. e.g. You have added public key of host B to authorized_keys in A. For a typical cluster, a RS cannot login to other RS directly for security.

For how to write graceful_stop.sh by yourself, you can look at: https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/cdh-user/fA3019_vpZY